# Conexão só funciona com valores setados manualmente

Tags: python, thread, socket, ini

Eu tenho uma classe Socket que esta funcionando normalmente desta forma:

```
class Socket():
    __ffChatSocket = ""
    __meuTelefone = ""
    __WhatsappAPI = ""
    __dest = ()

    def __init__(self, telefone, WhatsappAPI):
        ip = str(self.getFileConfigFF('infoserver','ip'))
        port = int(self.getFileConfigFF('infoserver','port'))
        self.__dest = (ip, port)
        self.__meuTelefone = telefone
        self.socketConnect()
        self.__WhatsappAPI = WhatsappAPI

    def socketConnect(self):
        try:
            self.__ffChatSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            self.__ffChatSocket.connect(("172.20.50.243", 4321)))
            self.__ffChatSocket.send(self.criarEvento("onCompleteConnection", [self.getNumeroFuturoFone()]))
            thread.start_new_thread(self.socketReceiveData, ())
        except Exception as erro:
            self.logErro("Conexao falhou ")
            self.logErro("O erro foi: ")
            self.logErro(erro)
            self.reconectarSocket()

    def getFileConfigFF(self, tag, subTag):
        Config = configparser.ConfigParser()
        pastaLocal = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
        Config.read(pastaLocal + '\config.ini')
        caminho = re.findall('"([^"]*)"', Config[tag][subTag])
        return caminho[0]
```

Mas eu quero pegar o ip e a porta por um arquivo .ini, já realizei varios testes utilizando o metodo getFileConfigFF e ele pega os valores normalmente.

Tentei atribuir os valores para o metodo connect de diversas formas como:

```
dest = (ip, port)
self.__ffChatSocket.connect(dest)
```

ou

```
self.__ffChatSocket.connect((ip, port))
```

Tentei pegar os valores utilizando cast (str e int) e também sem o cast, mas ele sempre apresenta o mesmo erro ao tentar conectar:

```
[Errno 10061] Nenhuma conexÒo p¶de ser feita porque a mßquina de destino as recusou ativamente
```

Este aqui é o ultimo código que eu testei:

```
class Socket():
    __ffChatSocket = ""
    __meuTelefone = ""
    __WhatsappAPI = ""
    __dest = ()

    def __init__(self, telefone, WhatsappAPI):
        ip = str(self.getFileConfigFF('infoserver','ip'))
        port = int(self.getFileConfigFF('infoserver','port'))
        self.__dest = (ip, port)
        self.__meuTelefone = telefone
        self.socketConnect()
        self.__WhatsappAPI = WhatsappAPI

    def socketConnect(self):
        try:
            self.__ffChatSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            pprint(self.__dest)
            self.__ffChatSocket.connect(self.__dest)
            self.__ffChatSocket.send(self.criarEvento("onCompleteConnection", [self.getNumeroFuturoFone()]))
            thread.start_new_thread(self.socketReceiveData, ())
        except Exception as erro:
            self.logErro("Conexao falhou ")
            self.logErro("O erro foi: ")
            self.logErro(erro)
            self.reconectarSocket()

    def getFileConfigFF(self, tag, subTag):
        Config = configparser.ConfigParser()
        pastaLocal = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
        Config.read(pastaLocal + '\config.ini')
        caminho = re.findall('"([^"]*)"', Config[tag][subTag])
        return caminho[0]
```

Coloquei pprint(self.__dest) antes da conexão para mostrar o valor que foi setado para self.__dest e o que é mostrado na tela é:

```
('172.20.50.247', 4433)
```

Ou seja o ip e a porta estão certos, mas não entendo o porque não esta conectado e porque conecta normalmente quando os valores são setados manualmente.

Comment: Você já conseguiu solucionar seu problema ? Seu código não está retornando nenhum erro quando tenta usar as configurações ?

Comment: O problema estava na hora de pegar o arquivo de configuração, já foi resolvido.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema era com encode, de como era pego os valores da porta e do ip.